# What is the word to describe something that occurs every work shift? "Shiftly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

A work shift is a set period of time that an employee may be expected to work for. A day shift might start at 07:00 in the morning and end at 15:00 in the afternoon. Then we will have an afternoon shift and then maybe a night shift.

If there is a task that must occur on each shift I would like to call that a "shiftly" task. Or if I create a production report that is generated each shift, it would be the "shiftly" report.

However "shiftly" appears to not be a word. What might I use in its place? Or should I ignore spellcheckers and use "shiftly" until they eventually catch up?

Comment: If it's a task common to every shift, why should it be a "shiftly" or shifting task? Rather, shouldn't it be a static or common task?

Comment: I think "shift" allows you to call it simply a "shift report" because of the clarity that "shift" means a work period. A "Day report" would mean something different and more ambiguous than a "daily report" (like when the sun is up, vs once per day?).  "afternoon report" would be pretty clear that it happened each afternoon.. you wouldn't say "afternoonly report" and I think "shift" would follow the same rule. (we don't say the "eveningly news"... or my "morningly cofee")

Comment: I've occasionally seen "shift-wise" used, but can't find any evidence that it's a recognized word.

Comment: I appreciate the comparison to morningly, afternoonly, etc. The report context can easily be gotten around by referring to the "shift reports". 

With tasks, there is an added complication that things may need to occur twice in a shift so I may would prefer to say "twice shiftly" instead of "twice per shift", perhaps a bit lazy.

At this point it seems I must abandon my use of the term shiftly in favour of referring to the "shift report" or things occurring "per shift".

Comment: A spellchecker must never be a factor in choosing your vocabulary. Ever. You are not writing for the spellchecker, you are writing for a human audience. Your readers do not know and do not care whether or not your spellchecker knows the word "shiftly" or "amaranthine" or "Jabberwocky" or "car" or "seven". It is completely irrelevant to them. All that matters is whether *they* know these words.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use **nightly** or **daily**?

They would achieve the same result and there is no confusion because a "shift report" cannot be done on a night or day when no one is working (i.e. when there is no shift occurring).

Comment: These work when being specific. I want to use shiftly to refer to something common to all shifts.
Shifts are not always separated into night, afternoon and day. Sometimes rosters are very complicated with shifts like WeekendA-Dayshift and WeekdayBCrew-Handovershift.

Comment: Then use *daily* or *per shift*.

Answer (score -2):

A "shiftly" report is using the word as an adjective which is acceptable.  To do something "shiftly" is attempting to used it as an adverb which is not. To my knowledge, there is no associated adverb unless you include shiftily, lol.